# Are Odoo rules working OK actually?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

**MY PURPOSE**

I'm trying to use security rules to achieve the following purpose:

I need to add in users model a field which will set which warehouses each user can modify. This is because I want to hide the stock moves you aren't allowed to see (stock moves of other warehouses).

**WHAT I DID**

I've created a *Many2many* field named `allowed_warehouses` in `res.users` model. From here, the administrator can select which warehouses can be used by each user.

Then, I took advantage of the existing fields of Odoo, `stock.move` model has a *Many2one* field named `picking_type_id`, pointing to `stock.picking.type` model. And `stock.picking.type` model has a *Many2one* field named `warehouse_id`, pointing to `stock.warehouse`.

So the rule was easy in theory:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="poc_stock_move_allowed_warehouses">
    <field name="name">stock.move: interaction only allowed if warehouse matches</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_move"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('picking_type_id.warehouse_id', 'in', user.allowed_warehouses.mapped('id'))]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

With this rule, I expected users to see only the stock moves of their allowed warehouses.

**THE RESULT**

Everything was working almost OK, and I say almost because some weird things are breaking down all the development. For example, I'm allowed to use all the warehouses, and I create a new picking with one stock move, this move has the *Product A*. I save, and everything goes fine. But if I do exactly the same but choosing *Product B* instead, I got an access error just after clicking on *Save* button, so I can't see the moves of that picking anymore. It seems that the move is forbidden for me (despite I should be seeing it), but not! If I go to look for this move in other view (for example in the *Traceability > Stock Moves* menu), I can see the move in the tree view, and open its form view with no errors! And if I modify the move in PostgreSQL and replace *Product B* with *Product A*, I can see the move from the picking view... Of course, if I remove my rule and restart the service, I can see the move in the picking view it doesn't matter if the product is *A* or *B*.

**MY CONCLUSION**

There must be some field in *Product B* which is shooting my rule, but I can't understand that because my rule is not affected by product fields, and if it was, why can I see the move in some views and not in other ones?

Please, can anyone help me with at least an idea, I'm running out of them!

Comment: That's the problem with the rules: you don't expect there influence on so many situations ;-) What about filtering the moves lists and the one2many fields directly? But this requirement is really complex and not easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you for commenting @CZoellner! Do you mean modifying every menuitem which takes you to `stock.move` views to apply a domain (using server actions in some cases)? And also every domain on fields related to `stock.move` (One2many, Many2many, Many2one)? I guess that's the only alternative I have if I can't make the rule work, but it'd be crazy to modify all those things.

Comment: Yes that's an alternative. But at first i would try to find the problem with Product B. Maybe that is only a little problem, which can be fixed by using sudo(). My first guess: the stock fields.